# $G$- simple graph. Show that it has a path of length at least $\dfrac{2m}{n}$ where $m=|E|$ and $n=|V|$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be simple graph. I need to show, that it has a simple path of length at least $\dfrac{2m}{n}$ where $m=|E(G)|$ and $n=|V(G)|$.

I tried induction on $n$. Then With $n=1$ we have single vertex and since it's a simple graph then $\dfrac{0}{1}=0$ and all is fine. Trivially $n=2$ also applies. But I fail with the induction step.

I tried something along this lines. Since $\dfrac{2m}{n}$ is an average of degrees, so let's take $x$ such that $deg(x) \leq$ average. If we erase it from the graph along with the edges adjacent to it, we will get a graph, for which the average is $\dfrac{2(m-deg(x))}{n-1}=\dfrac{2m}{n-1}-\dfrac{2deg(x)}{n-1} \geq \dfrac{2m}{n-1}-\dfrac{4m}{(n-1)(n)}$, and I would like it to be bigger $\dfrac{2m}{n}$ but I'm not sure it is...

Comment: Unfortunately this approach would imply the *subgraph* has a simple path of length $\frac{2m}{n}$, and then you could keep repeating the argument...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in the [blog entry](http://www.chaoxuprime.com/posts/2013-01-30-there-exist-a-path-of-length-d-g-for-every-graph-g.html) by [Chao Xu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/96/chao-xu) (note that I copy this for the case that the blog might not be reachable in the future):

> $G$ is a simple graph, then $d(G) = \frac{2e(G)}{|G|}$ be the average degree of a simple graph.
>
> **Lemma 1**
>
> If $G$ is a connected graph, then it contain a path of length $\min(2\delta(G), |G|-1)$, where $\delta(G)$ is the minimum degree of $G$. (exercise 1.7. in Graph Theory by Diestel)
>
> **Lemma 2**
>
> Every graph $G$ has a component $H$, such that $d(H)\geq d(G)$.
>
> **Proof**
>
> Fact: If $x_i,y_i>0$ and $\frac{x_i}{y_i} < t$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$, then $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^k y_i} < t$. Assume the lemma is false, then consider all it's components $H_1,\ldots,H_k$, $d(H_i) = \frac{2e(H_i)}{|H_i|} < d(G)$, then $d(G) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k 2e(H_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^k |H_i|} < d(G)$, a contradiction.
>
> **Theorem**
>
> A simple graph $G$ must contain a path of length at least $d(G)$.
>
> **Proof**
>
> Proof by induction. It is true for graph with 1 vertex. Assume it is true for all graphs with $k$ vertices, $k < n$. Consider graph $G$ of $n$ vertices. If the graph has more than 1 component, then we use [Lemma 2] and show there exist a subgraph $H$ with strictly smaller number of vertices, such that $d(H)\geq d(G)$, and just apply the induction hypothesis.
>
> Otherwise, the graph is connected. If there exist a vertex $v$ with degree at most $\frac{1}{2}d(G)$, we can remove it, and $d(G-v) \geq d(G)$, then by inductive hypothesis, in $d(G-v)$ there will be a path of length at least $d(G)$. If there is no such vertex. then we must have $\delta(G) > \frac{1}{2} d(G)$. By [Lemma 1], we have it has a path of length $\min(2 \delta(G) ,|G|-1)$. $2\delta(G) \geq d(G)$ and $d(G)\leq |G|-1$, thus it contain a path of length at least $d(G)$.

Comment: This still leaves open the question of how to prove lemma 1, though...