# For any graph there is at least a path of length m/n or longer

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am trying to prove that for any graph there is at least a path of length $m/n$ or longer where $m$ is the number of edges and $n$ is the number of vertexes. I don't know how to start the approach. Should I use structural induction and if yes how should I start it?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I can't figure the correlation between m/n and the length of the path. The only thing I know is that if m/n < 1 then there are no cycles and if m/n > 2 then there is at least a cycle of length ≥δ(G)+1

Comment: Over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629299/g-simple-graph-show-that-it-has-a-path-of-length-at-least-dfrac2mn-wh) is a similar question.